# Where is the angular-cli package directory?

Tags: intellij-idea, angular-cli

I'm trying to create a new Angular CLI project stub as instructed in the IntelliJ docs here [Generating an Angular application stub using Angular CLI](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/using-angular.html#d461255e168). One of the mandatory fields asks for the Angular CLI package directory.

I have no idea what this is or where to find this.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Angular CLI field value should be something similar to: C:\Users[user name here]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli as @lena mentioned

**The problem:**  I had an old version of angular-cli installed. Even though I followed the Intellij docs for creating an Angular stub project, and installed the new @angular/cli via npm install, the new cli directory was not present.

**The solution:** I followed the instruction from [updating-angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli) and this installed the updated @angular\cli directory which then allowed Intellij IDEA to correctly build the Angular module. You have to uninstall old versions before installing the new cli. I was then able to point the Angular CLI field to the above path and the module generated correctly.

Answer (score 5):

As it's written in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/using-angular.html#d461255e133, you need to install [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/) module first: `npm install -g @angular/cli`.

Once the package is installed, specify a path to it in **Angular CLI** field. In your environment, it should be smth like `C:\Users\andyrh3\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli`

Comment: Thank you @lena but this directory simply didn't exist on my system. The way I fixed this was to ensure I had the latest Node.js installed by downloading it a fresh and running the Windows setup, then following the instructions for updating from old cli to new from [https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli)

Comment: sure - you won't find this folder unless you have `@angular/cli` installed globally.

Comment: Hi Lena. I was unaware at the time that this was the problem that's why I was reaching out for help. I didn't realise that having the old cli installed would prevent the new cli from creating the new directory structure. Sorry if I misled you but this was not my intention.

Answer (score 2):

for Ubuntu point to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all above answers are correct if anyone wants to see screenshot folder location here it is :

**C:\Users\SWAPNIL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I work on windows, find all the modules installed **globally by npm** at:

```
> c:/users/<user-name>/appData/roaming/npm
> c:/users/<user-name>/appData/roaming/npm-cache
```

To Be exact for **angular-cli**:

```
> c:/users/<user-name>/appData/roaming/npm-cache/@angular/cli
```